# Simple Modal opens PHP records based on ID

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, simplemodal

I'm trying to open a php record inside of simple modal box. I already tried to open a record using fancybox.

In fancybox just like this

```
<td><a class="fancybox" href="url.php?id='.$row["id"].'"><img src=".png"></a></td>
```

How to do that in simple modal?

SimpleModal

```
     $("myElement").addEvent("click", function(){
  var SM = new SimpleModal({"width":600});
      SM.addButton("Action button", "btn primary", function(){
          this.hide();
      });
      SM.addButton("Cancel", "btn");
      SM.show({
        "model":"modal-ajax",
        "title":"Title",
        "param":{
          "url":"ajax-content.php",
          "onRequestComplete": function(){ /* Action on request complete */ }
        }
      });
});

<li class="example-item" id="modal-ajax">
<img src=".jpg">
<a href="#">Modal Ajax</a></li>
```

Comment: I haven't used SimpleModal before, but it looks like you change `ajax-content.php` to `url.php?id=<?=$row["id"]?>`

Comment: I think you may be confusing the [Mootools SimpleModal](http://mootools.net/forge/p/simplemodal) with the [jQuery one](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)...

Comment: @Owlvark how I can link the records id to open in modalbox?

Comment: 1. Are you including the [Mootools framework](http://mootools.net/download)? 2. Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Owlvark I didn't try it. I don't know how to link my td records link to open it to modal box.